# Can a website use multiple .htaccess files if it exists multiple times in the file tree?

Tags: .htaccess, filetree

I was actually wondering,

If I'd put a .htaccess in the `/public_html` folder and inside the `/public_html/example_site/`, would the pages inside `/public_html/example_site/` use both of them?

And which of the two would be in favor, in case of conflicting arguments?

***Use case***
*There are some rules I want to apply to every website I host, but there are some site-specific .htaccess rules. Therefor I would like to use two (or more) .htaccess files.*

Comment: I'm unsure if you can use multiple .htacess files however you can certainly make rules that only target a single domain which would definately meet your use case

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` files apply to a directory and its subdirectories. “Deeper” ones have precedence over those which are higher in the directory structure.

By the way, if you have access to the Apache configuration itself, you should put directives there and disable .htaccess (`AllowOverride None`) completely. Otherwise, the webserver must scan each directory for a `.htaccess` file.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer your **first question**, if `/public_html/example_site/.htaccess` exists then it will take precedence over `/public_html/.htaccess`. If lower level .htaccess exists then directives in `/public_html/.htaccess` won't be used at all.

Now **second question**:

> Use case
>   There are some rules I want to apply to every website I host, but there are some site-specific .htaccess rules. Therefor I would like to use two (or more) .htaccess files.

If you want directives from parent .htaccess to be used then use:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

But remember that rules inherited from the parent scope are applied *after* rules specified in the child scope.